# Signing Android APK using Release

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-play, keytool, jarsigner

I have created an Android App using Eclipse. I can't upload it to Android Market because it is signed using debug mode.
I want to Sign it in Release mode, I read the Tutorial [Basic Setup for Signing](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#setup), I also installed the `keytool` but don't know how to install `jarsigner`.

How can I accomplish the task of **compling and getting the APK in release mode**?

Thanks.

Comment: why not use `Android Tool` to sign the apk file. `Right Click on your Project > Android Tools > Export Signed Application Package..`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jarsigner comes with the JDK (look in the bin directory). I'd suggest using the [Export Wizard](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#ExportWizard) in Eclipse/ADT to export and sign your jar, which steps you through the whole process.

Comment: You will need to create a new keystore if you haven't created one already. The location is where the keystore is saved. Note: the keystore is important -- you can't update your app on the Play Store if you lose the original one you used to sign the app, so keep it somewhere safe.

Comment: how to create a keystore? This is the question

Comment: The wizard does it for you. Just give a location to save it to and a password.